# Creating custom blocks

Tags: 8, blocks

I am  building a custom block. The content of module_name/src/Plugin/Block/MyCustomblockName.php is the following.

```
    namespace Drupal\module_name\Plugin\Block;

    use Drupal\block\BlockBase;
    use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

    /**
     * Provides a 'Demo' block.
     *
     * @Block(
     *   id = "demo_block",
     *   admin_label = @Translation("Demo block"),
     * )
     */

    class MyCustomblockName extends BlockBase {

      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      public function build() {    
        return array(
          '#markup' => $this->t('Hello World!'),
        );
      }

      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */

  public function access(AccountInterface $account) {
    return $account->hasPermission('access content');
  }  

}
```

It doesn't display the block at all. What could be the reason?

Comment: remove the access method and instead define permissions in permissions.yml

Comment: i commented out that one inside access method and was not working

Comment: And now go to structure > BlockLayout and click on Place block . You can find your block

Comment: I see the block when i clicked on place block , but some how its not displaying

Comment: use use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase; instead of use Drupal\block\BlockBase; Flush cache and check .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. From the above code replace:

   ```
   use Drupal\block\BlockBase;
   ```

   with:

   ```
   use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
   ```

   Then *Flush cache* and check.
2. Go to *Structure*, *BlockLayout* and click on *Place block*.